# What time format is this: 1384915445000?

Tags: datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to understand a third party system which gives timestamp in the format as '1384915445000'. An example of the system output entry is as follows:

> "#A6","Address","Timestamp","MessageType","UserName","StnName","PairKey","ShelfID","TargetTimestamp","stShelfIDBeforeRelease","SrcStnNo","AlarmType","SubCondition","GroupID"
>
> "A4A1","0x00000000","1384915445000","1384915445617.82","Start (
>   Virtual
>   )","0","238","System","238","HIS0164","","","","","Low","","","","","","","","0"

Does anybody know this time stamp format?

Comment: please accept an answers if it was the satisfactory :)

Answer (score 5):

It's a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), but in milliseconds instead of seconds.

1384915445000ms = 1384915445s = Wed, 20 Nov 2013 02:44:05 GMT

Comment: Thanks! you guys are awesomoooooo!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) containing milliseconds.

So

1384915445000 milliseconds = 1384915445 seconds

And 1384915445 = November, 20 2013 02:44:05+0000

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/34874)**